# How to monitor a diode with an LED?

Tags: led, diodes, power-electronics

I have a circuit containing diodes.  These diodes are operating at a higher power than could be handled by an LED.  I would like to monitor each of these diodes with an LED.  When current is flowing through each diode, I want the corresponding LED to light.  There aren't LEDs rated to the voltage or current that I need.  How would I go about firing the LED whenever current is flowing in the respective power diode?

**Some more data:**

The source voltage for the power diode will be mains.  120VAC RMS.  For the minimum current on the power diode to trigger the LED, I think 50mA should be ok.  If it would be more convenient to make that higher (or lower), that might be doable.  The steady state current through the power diode will be in the range of  200mA.

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is a current sense resistor in series with the power diode and then use an analog comparator to measure the voltage across it against the threshold you want.  Output of comparator triggers the LED.

Comment: "These diodes are operating at a high power". . . What power? What current? If you want good answers, give good data.

Comment: A shunt resistor and measure the voltage across it?

Comment: A comparator that detects when there is forward voltage across the diode?

Comment: @winny if the power diodes are conducting, there will be a forward voltage across them. Assuming they are silicon diodes, one could just check that forward voltage.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy Indeed, but OP is dubious.

Comment: winny I should have directed my comment to @SteKulov. Sorry.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy  Yeah, I gotcha.  I wasn't sure how accurate the sensing had to be so I proposed something more generic where you could sense a precise level due to the linearity of a resistor vs a non-linear diode I-V curve.

Comment: @SteKulov yes, we are missing specs on such things as the minimum power diode current needed to trigger the LED and the maximum current that will not trigger the LED. Given that the characteristics of the diode will change with heating, a precision shunt resistor may be necessary. So good point. :-) Let's see what the question author has to say about these requirements.

Comment: Tripp, I assume you are just looking on but not engaging discussion. So [here](https://www.digikey.com/en/articles/hall-effect-sensing-provides-current-measurement-for-the-smart-grid) is another page to consider.

Comment: I see that your idea of high power is much different from mine, where I assumed the current would be in the order of several amperes, and I used that assumption for my answer. That basic circuit should still work for 50-200 mA, with obvious component value changes. Instead of a series resistor, however, an additional series diode should work even better, if your application can tolerate an additional 800mV or so.

Comment: **What is the load on those diodes?** That's very important, because things will differ quite a bit between a mains-rectifying diode loaded with, say, a resistor, and one loaded with a capacitor.

Comment: **Are the diodes single diodes, or rectifier bridges?** That also greatly impacts the answer :)

Comment: There is a comment to the effect that the more information you give us, the higher quality answers you will receive. Rather than give us information in drips and drabs, tell us everything you can about what you are trying to achieve, what the existing circuits do, and what components they use, etc. It will make our job much easier, and you will be more satisfied with the result.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica It would be optimal to work in either situation.  I'd like to be able to plug it into a circuit roughly where just the power diode would go to add a visible indicator.

Comment: @PStechPaul When I was saying "high power", I guess mostly I meant "higher power than anything any LED could take".  I should have been more clear.

Answer (score 3):

This might work. The forward voltage of the power diode (along with the voltage drop of the series resistor) should be higher than the B-E voltage of the transistor, which will light the LED on the positive excursions of the current.

There are limits to the range of load, imposed by specific values of components. This example works from about 1 Amp RMS and above. While power dissipation in R4 is just about 250 mW at 1 A, it becomes about 25 watts at 10 amps. It might be possible to replace R4 with an NTC thermistor to reduce power at high current.

Even better might be another diode (even a Schottky) in series to get adequate voltage. I tried adding a BAT54 and the circuit works even with a 1k load. R1 can be reduced to 100 ohms to get more current (10 mA) for the LED.

(edit2) I see that D3 is reversed. So I edited the schematic to fix that, changed R4 from a 500 mOhm resistor to a Schottky diode, Changed R1 from 220 ohms to 20k, and imposed a 1k load. There will be about 5 mA reverse current through R1 and D3, so R1 will dissipate about 1/2 watt during reverse AC voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffyqgx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: Voltages]

[image: LED Current]

Comment: Yeah, actually D3 was reversed. Now it properly shunts reverse current to avoid high voltage on Q2 B-E junction.

Comment: Instead of D1 and D4 in series, a UF4007 can be used. The problem with this circuit is, though, that it doesn't actually measure current. If you remove D1, it'll still pretend everything is A-OK. Also, forward diode voltages in rectifier-into-capacitor loads are quite a bit higher than 0.7V unless the diode is vastly oversized for the application.

Comment: One possible fix would be a red LED and resistor (around 10k) across the diodes, so an open circuit would cause it to light up.

Comment: Also note that R2 dissipates about 3W, and D2's peak reverse voltage is very likely exceeded.

Comment: So a 1N4004 diode in series with the LED should take care of the reverse voltage problem. And with 50% duty cycle I get about 3/4 watt. Before actually building and using this circuit, it should be more thoroughly analyzed using LTspice. Thanks for pointing out possible problems,

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica For my purposes, the absence of D1 not affecting the behavior of the D2 LED doesn't cause a problem.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to assume your power diodes are silicon PN power diodes, (not Schottky diodes) with a forward voltage across them of 0.65-0.75 volts.

Unfortunately, the voltage across a power diode is less than the voltage required to get an LED to light. So, merely putting your LED in parallel with the power diode will not be sufficient.

There are three approaches one might take to have enough voltage to light the LED.

The first is to steal some voltage/power from your circuit. Presumably, the power diode provides current for some load, and you could place a circuit in parallel with that load which will light the LED when the load has sufficient voltage.

The second approach would be to use a DC-DC boost converter to convert the voltage across the diode to a higher voltage. Most DC-DC converters will not work at the low voltage across a power diode. However, you might be able to get a joule thief circuit to work. Warning, joule thief circuits are temperamental.

The third approach is to get some power external to either your diodes or the load. In some cases, such power may be readily available, and in other cases not.

Whichever approach you take, you will need to provide some method of giving current limited power to the LED when the power diode is conducting.

If you provide more details about your overall circuit, and your preferred approach, one could provide a more detailed approach to a solution.

Answer (score 1):

> These diodes are operating at a high power.

> The steady state current through the power diode will be in the range of 200mA.

As an aside: These two statements contradict each other. 200mA through a typical through-hole rectifier diode is nothing much. I'm not sure anyone would call it "high power". If anything, it's neither particularly high nor particularly low power - although that's a bit application specific. Any modern rectifier diode in through hole package will handle 200mA RMS with a large factor of safety, even in hot environment.

Perhaps you're too concerned for these diodes, thinking that they are working "high power", when they don't quite?

---

> When current is flowing through each diode, I want the corresponding LED to light.

If you replace a diode with a piece of wire, you'll still have current flowing through it. Is that what you want? An indicator of any current, whether diode has failed short or not? When diodes fail short, things will be getting rather toasty elsewhere in the circuit, and hopefully the fuse is properly rated to prevent a fire. But perhaps you don't care that the diode failed short?

If all you wanted is a current meter, then the fact you measure a current flowing through a diode is of course helpful (forward voltage!), but it won't affect much how the measurement is made. Either you use the diode as a current shunt, or add a series current shunt, or use an electromagnetic sensor - a core with a hall sensor, usually bought as a **DC current sensor module**. The latter would be the easiest way to do it, because it also galvanically isolates the sensing output from mains.

So, for example to me, a reasonable interpretation of your requirement would be:

- Detect when the diode forward conducts more than 50m RMS (or a 1/2 or 1/4 of it, depending on how many diodes feed the same load).

Say then that we confirm the diode in fact only conducts in the right direction, and that it is conducting sufficient RMS current.

The requirement to measure RMS current is a complication of sorts, because it's a bit harder to do than measuring the average current.

When the diode is loaded with a resistance, we roughly know the shape of the current: a one-way rectified sinusoidal current. So it's easy to convert average current into RMS current. Similarly, highly inductive load would also be easy to predict the waveforms for, and the conduction angle could be converted to current rather easily, making the whole thing easy, since very little precision in voltage measurement is needed.

But, if the diode is loaded with a capacitance, then the diode current will consist of pulses **much higher** than 50mA. 50mA would be the RMS value (actually 12.5mA if a full bridge rectifier is used and not just a single diode), but the diode will be conducting only for a short part of the mains cycle. To accurately measure that on the rectifier output is a bit harder.

So, here is another approach:

Do you really care about the status of a single diode independently of that of other diodes in the same rectifier bridge? Are you using a rectifier bridge?

If the diodes are in a rectifier bridge, then, on average, their time integrals of forward voltage should be approximately the same. If any one of them diverges greatly, we know that the diode is a "dud" and has failed either open or short. So at least the detection of the failure of a single diode would be easy - and you'd only need a single red "bad diode" indicator for the entire bridge. Aggregate bridge current would be the other thing to measure then, lighting a green indicator (meaning: things are good).

---

Now let's look at a rough simulation of how a voltage and current look through a basic 1N4005 diode feeding a capacitor loaded with a 50mA current sink - the smallest value we care to detect. The circuit has is fed from a 120VRMS (170Vp-p) 60Hz source representing mains, then we have the diode, then the smoothing capacitor with some aggregate series resistance present in the loop from the ideal voltage source through the capacitor. The load is a steady 50mA current.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsGmIM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The mains and capacitor voltage waveforms look as follows:

[image]

The diode current is plotted for the distributed equivalent series resistance (ESR) in the mains source and the capacitor in aggregate of 0.1Ω, 0.5Ω, 1Ω and 5Ω. The lower the series resistance in the circuit, the higher the current peaks:

[image]

Now, this simulation isn't accurate enough to know the real pulsed current value, but it's good enough to understand the general behavior of a single-diode rectifier circuit.

The voltage across the diode, magnified around the forward conduction point, is:

[image]

We can expect about 0.9V of forward voltage.

How good is this expectation? Let's build an actual circuit and measure! The forward voltage across the diode won't change much no matter the absolute voltage, so to keep things safer for myself, I'll run the circuit from about 24VAC. The load will be dissipating under 2W at 50mA, and can be approximated with a 680Ω resistor. I've got 5x3.3kΩ in parallel for a 660Ω load, and the AC voltage I have available is 29VAC(RMS). So the RMS current is a bit above 50mA.

The conduction period forward diode voltage of 1N4003 looks as follows:

[image]

The shape doesn't look far from what the simulation would make us expect. The peak value is indeed about 0.9V. That's convenient :)

I've recorded this peak forward voltage for a ~60mA load for both 1N4003 and UF4003. For straight-to-mains you'll probably want 1N4005 or UF4005, or even 1N4007 or UF4007, to have some margin against transient overvoltages.

Why a UF diode? Because it's less electrically noisy. It switches faster, so the reverse current doesn't have time to build up before it's cut off. That way there's less of an inductive spike from the transformer winding's leakage inductance. Look below: it's 1N4003 replaced with UF4003. The oscilloscope bandwidth is set to 20MHz in both cases:

[image]

The thin low-going spike is gone, as expected. This is why I always highly suggest not to use slow 1N400x diode in mains rectifier applications in anything destined for the bench or for lab use - at least not without mitigating the fallout from slow reverse recovery.

---

So, now that we know what we're measuring, let's say we'd like to have our monitor act as follows:

1. Diode open: green LED off (independent of load), optional red LED on
2. Diode shorted or conducting in both directions: green LED off (independent of load), optional red LED on
3. Diode OK, no load: green LED off, optional red LED off
4. Diode OK, under at least 50mA load drawn from a smoothing capacitor of at least 100uF capacitance: green LED on, optional red LED off

We also assume that the monitor does not have a separate power source, and should work from the mains without a transformer. That means that in addition to the monitor circuit, we'll also need a reasonable power source for it. IMHO reasonable means dissipating very little power, commensurate with the little power the monitor would dissipate.

These tasks are most compactly done with an 8-pin microcontroller and a few passive components, but I'll try for an analog solution in a future installment of this answer. Stay tuned :)

Comment: When I say "high power", I'm talking about higher power than an LED can handle by itself.

Comment: Replacing the diode with a piece of wire would not behave the same under reverse voltage.

Comment: I am not interested in showing when the diode is conducting RMS current.  I am only interested when it's conducting in the forward direction.  So, the LED should be off for half the cycle on a regular sine wave.

Comment: I am indeed not interested in monitoring whether the diode has failed in any way.

Comment: The monitoring I'm expecting is much simpler than what you're proposing.  I just want an LED to light whenever the power diode is conducting forward current and not otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

How about

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ff3s3q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The voltage being unspecified, B.E.R.="Big Enough Resistor".   One light = good diode. Two lights = open diode.  No lights = shorted diode.  For fun, the "good" LED is green.

Comment: This has no chance of working in the forward direction.

Comment: The forward direction LED should never light.

Answer (score -1):

A LED is at the same time a photodiode.If you move close to a LED a light source then turn it off you can see its current changes.However why not use a optocoupler?And connect the optocoupler in series with the LED as well as probably a resistor?

Comment: How would that accomplishing a non-LED diode?